# I/O communication in Java - to what part of MVC does it belong?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have divided my project into three packages: model, controller, view. But I am still confused where to put the classes which deal with I/O communication in my application - in my case the I/O communication is done by network sockets reading incoming messages which have an effect to the model.

I've been told three things now:

- it belongs to the controller, since it deals with transferring the data
- it belongs to the model, since every aspect of the domain model should be part of the model
- none if it, put it in a separate package or the default package

Currently I am going with the third advice, however I am still thinking it might be the second point. Could someone clarify what is meant in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually there's a service package that is services the controller makes use of. It would fit nicely there.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I would make it its own seperate package and call it/use it from the controlller. The controller is the section that will access this information and give it to the model etc...

Answer (score 1):

I'd put it in the model class, or, *possibly* in another class which in turn updates the model.

I'd definitely *not* put it in the controller, since the controller in MVC is all about bridging the view to the model.